# comparar uma linha inteira de uma matriz

Tags: c

O que quero fazer é simples: eu quero comparar uma matriz ou uma linha inteira de variáveis de uma matriz em busca de determinados valores em ordem

`var[2][]=={1,2,3,4,5} //inteiro. todos de uma vez`

em vez de

`var[2][0]==1 && var[2][1]==2 && var[2][2]==3 && var[2][3]==4 && var[2][4]==5 //inteiro. um por um`

ou então

`vartwo[4][3...7]==var[2][]` ou `vartwo[4][]==var[2][]`

Answer (score 0):

Dá uma olhada no código abaixo, a fonte está no final do código. Abraço.

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* Searches the element x in mat[][]. If the 
element is found, then prints its position 
and returns true, otherwise prints "not found"
and returns false */
int search(int mat[4][4], int n, int x) {
  int i = 0, j = n-1;  //set indexes for top right element
  while ( i < n && j >= 0 ) {
   if ( mat[i][j] == x ) {
     printf("n Found at %d, %d", i, j);
     return 1;
   }
   if ( mat[i][j] > x )
     j--;
   else //  if mat[i][j] < x
     i++;
   }

  printf("n Element not found");
  return 0;  // if ( i==n || j== -1 )
}

// driver program to test above function
int main()
{
 int mat[4][4] = {{10, 20, 30, 40},
                 {15, 25, 35, 45},
                 {27, 29, 37, 48},
                 {32, 33, 39, 50},
};
search(mat, 4, 29);
return 0;
}
```

**http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-in-row-wise-and-column-wise-sorted-matrix/**

Comment: eu não entendi muito bem. minha intenção é de conseguir verdadeiro ou falso para usar em itens de `if/else` como

`if (//comparação de matriz) {
    //do stuff
}`